# Not getting value from tuple

Tags: hcl

I have the following input

```
id_pass = [
        {
            ipv4 = "projects/project_1234/regions/europe-west1/forwardingRules/network-ilb-ent-ipv4"
            ipv6 = "projects/project_1234/regions/europe-west1/forwardingRules/network-ilb-ent-ipv6"
        },
    ]
```

I need value of ipv4 = "projects/project_1234/regions/europe-west1/forwardingRules/network-ilb-ent-ipv4"
I am using value = id_pass[0]["ipv4"], but it failed ,
how I get value for ipv4 hcl test file.

Thanks in advance
Ajit